# calculus, finding continuous and differential of function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

$$\forall a\in \mathbb{R}, f(x)= \begin{cases}x+xe^{1/x}
 & \text{ if } x<0 \\ 
0 & \text{ if } x=0 \\ 
{{(a-2\cos x)}/{sin x}}& \text{ if } x>0 
\end{cases}$$

1. find all $a$ values for $f(x)$ will be continuous at $x=0$
2. find all $a$ values for $f(x)$ will be differentiable at $x=0$

Comment: well, our teacher said this clue: find what happens when $a=2$ and what else happens when $a\neq2$.

Comment: Why don't you check the answer below the only possible value for a is 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

f is continuous at 0 if $\lim_{x\to 0^-}f(x) =0=\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)$ that is 
$$0= \lim_{x\to 0^-}(x+xe^{1/x})=\lim_{x\to 0^+}
\frac{(a-2\cos x)}{\sin x}  = \lim_{x\to 0^+}
\frac{(a-2\cos x)}{ x} \lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{x}{\sin x}$$

But we  have , $$ \lim_{x\to 0^-}(x+xe^{1/x}) = 0~~~and ~~~\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{x}{\sin x}=1$$
sO, it is true if and only if

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}
\frac{(a-2\cos x)}{ x} =0 =\lim_{x\to 0^+}
\frac{(\frac{a}{2}-1+ 1-\cos x)}{ x} = \lim_{x\to 0^+}
\frac{\frac{a}{2}-1}{ x}$$

Since $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}
\frac{1-\cos x}{ x} =\cos'(0)=\sin (0)= 0$$
Hence the only possibility is $$\color{red}{a=2}$$

Comment: what about the difderentiabily